# How to convert columns of arrays[String] to columns of String

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In scala+spark, I'm having a dataframe of two columns of `Array[String]`

```java
scala> val test = spark.sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize(Seq("""{"v1":["A", "B", "C"],"v2":["ok", "false", "ok"]}""", """{"v1":["D", "E"],"v2":["false", "ok"]}""")))
test: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [v1: array<string>, v2: array<string>]

scala> test.show
+---------+---------------+
|       v1|             v2|
+---------+---------------+
|[A, B, C]|[ok, false, ok]|
|   [D, E]|    [false, ok]|
+---------+---------------+

scala> test.printSchema
root
 |-- v1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- v2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I would like to filter the element in `v1` based on the value of the corresponding index in `v2`

I zipped the two columns to try filtering it but I don't see how to do it with `.filter()` on a `Row` of `Array[String]`

```java
scala> val result = test.withColumn("result", arrays_zip($"v1", $"v2")).select("result")
result: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [result: array<struct<v1:string,v2:string>>]

scala> result.printSchema
root
 |-- result: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- v1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- v2: string (nullable = true)


scala> result.show
+--------------------+
|              result|
+--------------------+
|[[A, ok], [B, fal...|
|[[D, false], [E, ...|
+--------------------+
```

Ideally, at the end, I want an row of value like where I'll count, sort and distinct values.

```
+------+
|result|
+------+
|     A|
|     C|
|     E|
+------+
```

I have 19milions row in the columns and each row array has a length around a thousand so I wanted for performance issue to mostly use spark functions and avoid UDF if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are almost there. You can apply `explode()` to zipped columns and then filter them on required codition. Below code will give you rows with `v2 = ok`, on which you can execute count, sort, distinct etc.

```
scala> val result = test.withColumn("result", explode(arrays_zip($"v1", $"v2"))).select("result")
result: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [result: struct<v1: string, v2: string>]

scala> result.show(false)
+----------+
|result    |
+----------+
|[A, ok]   |
|[B, false]|
|[C, ok]   |
|[D, false]|
|[E, ok]   |
+----------+


scala> val data = result.filter(col("result.v2").equalTo("ok")).select(col("result.v1"))
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [v1: string]

scala> data.show
+---+
| v1|
+---+
|  A|
|  C|
|  E|
+---+
```